# Deploy a file to the installation folder

Tags: uwp

To deploy a file with the file name test.txt, I put it under Assets in Visual Studio 2015 and set it to content. I can access it using:

```
Platform::String^ appInstallFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path;

std::wstring folderNameW(appInstallFolder->Begin());
std::string folderNameA(folderNameW.begin(), folderNameW.end());

std::string fileName = folderNameA + "\\test.txt";
```

However, when I deploy from another computer, to access the file I have to use:

```
std::string fileName = folderNameA + "\\Assets\\test.txt";
```

I just copy the project from one compute to another one and did not change anything. I am confused why the path is different.

Thanks a lot.

YL

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue in my side. I suppose the path of Visual Studio within another compute different from your current compute.  And the best practice of getting file from `Assets` folder is using `Windows.Storage` Api.

```
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Test.txt");
```

And use the above method that get file in the `InstalledLocation` folder could avoid the path error.

Comment: Thank you Nico. I installed VS using the default setting and I think they have the same path. I cannot understand why the txt file was deployed to different pathes.

Comment: Does the path same  after re-install VS?